# SKscene class crashing, "Can't add body <SKPhysicsBody> ..."

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

For visual simplicity in order to position the node at correct location I create a file.sks called "ECAM_DOOR.sks"

In order to add some logic to my app I then create another scene where on it I want to load the scene I created from the editor.

But I'm getting the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Cant add body, already exists in a world', reason: 'Cant add body <SKPhysicsBody> type:<Rectangle> representedObject:[<SKScene> name:'Doors' frame:{{-512, -512}, {1024, 1024}} anchor:{0.5, 0.5}], already exists in a world'
```

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import SceneKit

class DOORS: SKScene, SKSceneDelegate {
    
    var systems: PlaneSystems
    
    init(size: CGSize,  systems: PlaneSystems) {
        self.systems = systems
        super.init(size: size)
        self.isPaused = false
        delegate = self
        prepareScene()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
       
    func prepareScene() {
        
        guard let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "/Asset.scnassets/ECAM_SYSTEM/ECAM_DOOR.sks") else {
            print("fail load ref door")
            return
        }
        
        
        self.addChild(scene)
    }
    
    
    
}
```

How I should I load sks file into my custom class DOORS?

Comment: If it's an `SKSpriteNode` object, try adding a copy.

Comment: unfortunately, still crash reporting the same error ` 'Cant add body <SKPhysicsBody> type:<Rectangle> representedObject:[<SKScene> name:'Doors' frame:{{-512, -512}, {1024, 1024}} anchor:{0.5, 0.5}], already exists in a world'`